# Check if website is available in fastest possible way

Tags: php, curl

```
foreach($links as $link_content)
{
  $handle = curl_init(LINK_BASE.$link_content);
  curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if($httpCode != 200)
    continue; //if not, go to next link
}
```

I need to analyse 350 links and check if each of them is available (returns HTTP code 200). Currently I use the code written above. Unfortunately, this operation takes a really long time - more than 2-4 minutes. I have to check each link in the fastest possible way. Can you give me any suggestions?

Comment: Are redirects considered "available"?

Comment: Hey, this is not a gimme the code service. This is a community where thinking people help each other. Not a place to have others done the work for free.

Comment: You already should be familiar with this concept. You already earned alot of points.

Comment: @T0xicCode - Don't you see? Reposne code should be 200

Comment: Should you not check to see whether the response code is `200 <= responsecode < 400`. Redirects don't mean the site is not available. It just means the resource has moved: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes. `4xx` and `5xx` status codes are usually errors. Anything other than that though is usually fine.

Comment: Are each of these links at the same site? Be careful about requesting them all (or a large number of them) from one site, since the admins might notice and block your IP (range) due to excessive requests. In this situation it is unavoidable for the whole series to take a long time - you need to put sleep between each one.

Answer (score 6):

I would say that you simply issue HTTP HEAD requests using `CURLOPT_NOBODY` rather than pull in the entire content as you are currently doing.  The code for this would look like:

```
foreach($links as $link_content)
{
  $handle = curl_init(LINK_BASE.$link_content);
  curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); // make HEAD
  $response = curl_exec($handle);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if($httpCode != 200)
    continue; //if not, go to next link
}
```

If this doesn't reduce time as much as desired, you can also look into using `curl_multi` functionality to parallelize your requests.  You can feel free to have a look at a simple curl-based REST class I have created to get some better examples on how to do `curl_multi`. You are welcome to use the class freely - https://github.com/mikecbrant/php-rest-client

Comment: C'mon @Ty221. You *know* SO is not a coding service.

Comment: @Ty221 Added some additional information to my answer, including code example.

Answer (score 1):

You could launch multiple instance of this PHP code separately. Imagine the gain of time with 10 parallel instances!

Create `crawler.php` file as below:

```
<?php
$fileName = argv[1];
$fh = fopen($fileName, "r");
while($link_content = fgets($fh) !== FALSE) {
    $handle = curl_init(LINK_BASE.$link_content);
    curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $response = curl_exec($handle);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if($httpCode != 200) {
        // log/output the bad URL
    }
}
?>
```

Create a bat file `crawler.bat` (if you are under Windows) and put this code:

```
php PathToCrawler/crawler.php %1
```

Now you have to distribute your URLS in different files and launch with console successively this bat:

```
crawler.bat UrlFileFrom1TO100.txt
crawler.bat UrlFileFrom101TO200.txt
crawler.bat UrlFileFrom201TO300.txt
crawler.bat UrlFileFrom301TO400.txt
...
```

Comment: Better yet would be to use `curl_multi` to manage multiple parallel curl requests in a single execution thread.