# cURL erros while asking for HTTP code

Tags: php, curl

I have this code now (after appyling fixes from this question: [Check if website is available in fastest possible way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849345/check-if-website-is-available-in-fastest-possible-way))

```
foreach($links as $link_content)
{
                $handle = curl_init(LINK_BASE.$link_content);
                curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD' );
                curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1 );
                curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
                $content = curl_exec ($handle);
                curl_close ($handle); //warning there!!!
                $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
                if($httpCode != 200)
                    continue; //if not, go to next link

}
```

Error log:

```
Warning: curl_getinfo(): 17 is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 82

Warning: curl_getinfo(): 18 is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 82

Warning: curl_getinfo(): 19 is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 82
```

I am not sure what is casuing this warning. Additionally, code doesn't work as expected. I continues loop in every case, also when website is available and returning code 200. Can you give me any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You're calling your cURL handle `$handle`:

```
$handle = curl_init(LINK_BASE.$link_content);
```

but then you're trying to use `$c` instead in your `curl_setopt` calls:

```
curl_setopt( $c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
```

Comment: I changed that - `Warning: curl_getinfo(): 17 is not a valid cURL handle resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 83` now I see this mistake...

Comment: @Ty221 So fix the issue on that line too. You did it four times.

Comment: Nope line 83 is - `$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);`

Comment: You close the handle before that line, which is why it's failing. You need to do some basic troubleshooting.